# Problema con FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

No entiendo el error que me da.

```
Mi código es el siguiente

public class PostsListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference categories;


    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts_list);


       recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
       recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
       layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
       firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
       categories = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Category");


    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model,ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>() {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder,Model model, int position){

            }
        };
    }
}
```

En la parte de abajo del todo podemos observar que tengo un FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, me da el siguiente error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si será la versión, no entiendo el error que me dice, si alguien me lo puede explicar estaría muy agradecido

Answer (score 0):

Te falta implementar el método `onBindViewHolder()`

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model,ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>() {
     @Override
     protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder,Model model, int position){

     }
     @Override
     protected void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position, Model model) {

     }
 };
```